# Rails: pluralize not functioning properly ? (quick)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi can anyone tell me why pluralize is giving me back

`This album currently has 0 photos`

when my html.erb is:

`<h1>This album currently has <%= pluralize(@album.photos.count, "photo") %></h1>`

? Am I misusing pluralize?

Comment: You're not misusing pluralize.  That's the correct phrase in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/photos#English

Rails may have a couple of wrong pluralizations/singularizations, for example:

```
"police".singularize
#=> "polouse"
```

But "photo" is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answers mentioned, that is the correct inflection. However as David Österreicher mentioned above, Rails does get it wrong sometimes. You can specify additional rules in `config/inflections.rb`. It comes with a couple of examples to get you on the right track.